# $4$ digit numbers greater then $4321$ using $0,1,2,3,4,5,$ if repetition is allowed

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> The number of $4$ digit numbers strictly greater then $4321$ that can be formed using the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5$ (Repetition of digits is allowed)

What I tried:

If $4$-digit number starts with $5,$ then total possibilities $6\cdot 6 \cdot 6=6^3$.

If $4$-digit number starts with $4,$ then total possibilities $3\cdot 4\cdot 5=60$.

Total ways $=216+60=276$.

But my answer is wrong.

Help me to solve it please.

Comment: Hello. How did you do the calculation for numbers beggined with $4$? Note that all beggined with $45,44$ are good, but not all beggined with $43$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The "fast" answer:

The number of 4-digit numbers greater than 4321 using digits in $\{0,1,...,5\}$ is equal to

$$5555_{(6}-4321_{(6}=1234_{(6}=310$$

where the subscript $5555_{(6}$ means that the number is written in base 6. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) for details on numbering in bases (radices) different from 10, and [here](https://online.math.uh.edu/Math2303-unpaid/ch1/s15/2303-Section-15.pdf) for details on how to do arithmetic in other bases.

### If you are not familiar with non-base-10 numbering:

You can get the same result by counting:

- All numbers that start with $5$: in total $6\cdot 6\cdot 6=216$ numbers.
- All numbers that start with $44$ or $45$: in total $2\cdot 6\cdot 6=72$ numbers.
- All numbers that start with $433$ or $434$ or $435$: in total $3\cdot 6=18$ numbers.
- All numbers tat start with $4322$ or $4323$ or $4324$ or $4325$: in total $4$ numbers.

**Grand total**:
 $$216+72+18+4=310$$

Note that the actual math done in both methods is the same:

$$1234_{(6}=1\cdot6\cdot 6\cdot 6 + 2\cdot 6\cdot 6 + 3\cdot 6 +4 =310$$